# RccpGSL, installing/using GSL from R on windows 7

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, gsl

I'm used to R but I'm a complete beginner in C++. I'm having a hard time installing GSL to use it with RcppGSL in R in order to refine a package comprising C++ code. I downloaded the latest GSL version, unpacked it to `C:/GSL`, set the environmental variable `LIB_GSL` to `C:/GSL` and the `PATH`to`C:/GSL/bin`.

Like I said, I want to refine an existing package. I've forked and pulled the latest version of the package in question from github. My primary goal is simply to be able to use and refine the package. However, when I'm trying to make a source package out of the source files I get the following Error:

```
Installing to library 'C:/Users/Simon/Documents/R/win-library/3.1'
* installing *source* package 'Rflim' ...
** libs
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Users/Simon/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"  -IC:/Users/Simon/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include -I/usr/local/include -I C:/Users/Simon/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppGSL/include   -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c flim.cpp -o flim.o
In file included from C:/Users/Simon/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppGSL/include/RcppGSL.h:23:0,
                 from flim.cpp:1:
C:/Users/Simon/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppGSL/include/RcppGSLForward.h:26:29: fatal error: gsl/gsl_vector.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [flim.o] Error 1
Warnung: Ausf�hrung von Kommando 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="Rflim.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="flim.o"' ergab Status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rflim'
* removing 'C:/Users/Simon/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rflim'

Exited with status 1.
```

*Sorry, there are a couple of german words in there: 
Warnung: Ausf�hrung von Kommando==Warning:executing command*

What I realize is that R is trying to access the GSL library via the RcppGSL path. Is that correct? Shouldn't it go directly to C:/GSL instead? I also realized that R is trying to go to paths from both Rcpp as well as RcppGSL and I don't see why...

I would appreciate any clarification or suggestions on how to solve the problem.

Thank you!!!

Comment: sry.. should have read the error message.

Comment: Can you locate the gsl header files (e.g. gsl_vector.h)  on your system?

Comment: Yes, they are here: C:\GSL\include\gsl

Comment: I guess the issue that the make file was written for a linux box, does including the header files under  /usr/local/include using -I /usr/local/include ... but in your case I think you should have something like -I C:\GSL\include\. So I guess you can either adjust the make file or throw the gsl headers in one of the windows directories which are already included (e.g. C:/Users/Simon/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RcppGSL/include/) .... (Disclaimer: I am by no means an expert on building R packages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please install the prebuild GSL version for R on Windows from the [support site provided by Prof Ripley](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/Rtools/libs.html) and then set these values accordingly in `src/Makevars.win`

```
## This assumes that the LIB_GSL variable points to working GSL libraries
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I$(LIB_GSL)/include -I../inst/include
PKG_LIBS=-L$(LIB_GSL)/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

either directly, or set `LIB_GSL` accordingly.

This is how CRAN builds the package, and it evidently works.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I have no doubts that this is the way to do it, but as a beginner I'm still unsure about how to use the makevars file correctly. There is, however, no makevars.win file in src to begin with. only makevars file tpe "saver box"

Comment: With Dirk's hand holding I managed to install GSL. The RcppGSLexample is working. The trick was to copy all files from C:/local320/lib/x64 to C:/local320/lib. The rest is just like Dirk mentioned.

Comment: The package I tried to install, as mentioned in the original question, still doesn't work though. But that doesn't seem to be a GSL problem....?